# How to disable BoxCollider2D on all prefabs?

Tags: unity, c#

I made a prefab that when hitting one object will disable it's box collider2d and enable it after hitting a different object.

It works find when there's one prefab, but when there's move, it only works on a single instance of the prefab and non of the others.

How do I set it to disable every box collider2d on every prefab object of that type? Thank you!

```
public void ChangeGreen()
{
     //Turns box collider2d on
     ColorBlockerController blockerScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PinkBlockerTag").GetComponent<ColorBlockerController>();
     blockerScript.PinkBoxOn();
}

public void ChangePink()
{         
     //Turns box collider2d off
     ColorBlockerController blockerScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PinkBlockerTag").GetComponent<ColorBlockerController>();
     blockerScript.PinkBoxOff();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag which will return all the similar gameobject and iterate though it

```
GameObject[] goWithSameTag = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TagNAme");
foreach(go in goWithSameTag)
{
    go.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
}
```

Alternatively you can cache these objects in an array at the start of game so you don't have to run call `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag` everytime you are enabling/disabling the collider.

Comment: Thanks, but when I put in the first line I got "CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject[]' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject' "

This it what I put-

GameObject pBlocker= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PinkBlockerTag");

Comment: @BrandonMccurdy `GameObject[] pBlocker= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PinkBlockerTag");` I think u may should review csharp a bit. It may save ur time later.

Comment: @BrandonMccurdy This answer contained a couple mistakes. I think I corrected them. Please try again.

Answer (score 2):

`FindGameObjectWithTag` works, but it is slow when you have a lot of objects.

You may find this event-based solution useful:

```
public class Whatever {
    private bool state;
    public event Action <bool> onStateChange;

    public bool State {
        get { return state; }
        set {
            state = value;
            onStateChange?.Invoke (value);
        }
    }
}
```

Store it in a static field or make its members static.

When you spawn a prefab, it first reads `State` and decided to enable collider or not, and subscribes to event:

```
whatever.onStateChange += SetColliderState;
```

In that handler you can do anything you want. For example:

```
private void SetColliderState (bool state) {
    boxCollider.enabled = state;
}
```

**Don't forget to unsubscribe in OnDestroy! If you don't, the object will not be garbage collected, and its handler will stay and be called forever!**